# C++ virtual function ignoring scope specifier

Tags: c++, scope, polymorphism, virtual, vtable

Please refer to the following C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() {}
    virtual void display() {
        std::cout << "Display A"  << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public A {
    // ! NO 'display()' function in this class.
};

class C : public B {
public:
    void display() {
        std::cout << "Display C" << std::endl;
        B::display();
    }
};


int main(void) {
    A* ptr = new C();
    ptr->display();
    delete ptr;

    return 0;
}
```

The is the output of this program:

```
Display C 
Display A
```

I would expect this program to have a compilation error since B::display() is not defined.

Could somebody explain the behaviour of this code?

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: `B` inherits `display` implementation from `A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could somebody explain the behaviour of this code?

`B` simply inherits the the `display` function from `A`. Since, it's virtual `B` could override the behavior to be something different (i.e., if it needs a different implementation it can make one otherwise it can take what it inherits).

Answer (score 1):

You're mistaking virtual functions with abstract functions. The function *is* virtual, insofar that it has a vtable entry that can be overwritten by subclasses of the base class. However the base class isn't required to overwrite the entry.

Case in point, the vtable entry for `B::display()` is `A::display()`, which is what you see in your example.

For completeness, you declare abstract functions in C++ like this: `virtual void display() =0;` with no body. This function has to be overriden for C++ to allow you to instantiate the class type, otherwise you'll get a compile error.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ Standard (10 Derived classes)

> 2. ...Unless redeclared in the derived class, members of a base class are
>      also considered to be members of the derived class. The base class
>      members are said to be inherited by the derived class. **Inherited
>      members can be referred to in expressions in the same manner as other
>      members of the derived class, unless their names are hidden or
>      ambiguous**...

So you may refer in class B inherited member function `display` declared in  class A the same way as other members of class B.